TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined in Angular Effects when accessing actions$ and service method
I have created an farmer.effects.ts file like this

@Injectable()
export class FarmerEffects {

  loadFarmers$ = createEffect(() => {
    console.log('actions$', this.actions$); ]
    console.log('farmerService.getFarmers()', this.farmerService.getFarmers());

    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(FarmerActions.farmers),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.farmerService.getFarmers().pipe(
          map(farmers => FarmerActions.farmersSuccess({ data: farmers })),
          catchError(error => of(FarmerActions.farmersFailure({ error })))
        )
      )
    );
  });

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private farmerService: FarmerService
  ) {
  
  }
}

whenI  run the application it says that this.actions$ is undefined and also 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFarmers')'  i used a simple service method to test this
getFarmers(): Observable<Farmer[]> {
    return of(this.staticDummyFarmers);
  }

However, when I run the application, I encounter the following errors:

this.actions$ is undefined

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFarmers')


I’m not sure why this.actions$ and this.farmerService are coming up as undefined in my effect class. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Ensured that FarmerService is provided in the module.

Logged the actions$ and farmerService.getFarmers() to debug, but both are undefined.


Could someone please help me identify what might be causing these issues and how to resolve them?

Have you checked for dependency injection issues or possible typo's/misconfiguration in Providers? Have you console logged through the workflow? What were the results?

Yeah. I checked those as well. That problem solved after adding "useDefineForClassFields": false,   in the tsconfig.json file.
